# Delete software from computer

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

i want to completely delete internet download manager from my win7. what should i do? where should i find files related to that software? should i remove something from registry?

thank you.

Answer (score 6):

[Revo Uninstaller](http://download.cnet.com/Revo-Uninstaller/3000-2096_4-10687648.html) is a good free program that will perform the normal uninstalling and then search the computer for left-overs (including registry and files), if it finds anything it allows you to delete it.

Comment: +1 for Revo Uninstaller. I've been using it for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired going to Control Panel -> Programs -> Unistall a Program.

Find the software in the list of installed programs and click Uninstall

Comment: yes but it does not delete the software completely. when i reinstall that software computer reminds it.

Answer (score 0):

"yes but it does not delete the software completely. when i reinstall that software computer reminds it. "

OH.. that kind of thing.. yeah, software can be clever like that! The only way to completely remove software, if it wants to leave something behind! is if you used an uninstaller to install it.. I tend not to do that, but it can be a good idea sometimes! in principle that should work! But doesn't apply to you on the comp you are on.. 'cos you didn't install it that way. You could try a system restore..